# Why is 3-co-SAT not in P?

Tags: np, decision-problem, co-np

The 3-co-SAT problem consists of deciding whether if a 3CNF formula, has an unsatisfiable assignment of variables, i.e., assignment of variables that evaluates to 0.

We know that 3-co-SAT is in coNP, however, I do not understand why it is also not in P? It seems to be very easy to check whether if there exists an unsatisfiable assignment of variables as follows:

1. Iteratively go through each clause.
2. For each clause try $2^3 = 8$ possible variable assignments. If there exists an assignment that makes the clause evaluate to False, accept.
3. If no clauses evaluated to False, reject.

This algorithm has runtime $8m$ where $m$ is the number of clauses, and it accepts a string if it is in coSAT no?

Comment: The definition of 3-co-SAT is deciding whether a formula is unsatisfiable, no? Not only whether it has some unsatisfying assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

co-SAT is not asking whether there exists an unsatisfying assignment, it is asking if every assignment evaluates to false.